# Is there a terminal tool to automatically generate autoconf/automake makefiles for a Vala project?

Tags: autotools, vala

I am trying to create a Vala project to see how i like developing with the language as a possible replacement for Mono. I think that the automake stuff can be used to generate a project template with all the necessary files (sans my .vala code).
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a sample skeleton Vala project called [Sampala](http://github.com/tadeboro/Sampala). You can clone it and start from there.

Answer (score 2):

Automake just recently added support for Vala. To find out more about it check out [Automake's notes](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Vala-Support.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Vala Toys for GEdit](http://code.google.com/p/vtg/) includes a tool called *vala-gen-project*. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code for the Vala compiler and look at 'configure.ac' and 'Makefile.am' in each subdirectory. Vala itself is the canonical example of how to build a Vala project.